# Why does this inequality hold, formally looking at it? Can someone prove this?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, metric-spaces

$$d_2, d_1-\text{metrics in } R^k$$

$$d_2(x,y)=(\sum_{i=1}^{k}|x^i-y^i|^2)^{1 \over 2} \\
  d_1(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}|x^i-y^i| \\ d_2(x,y) \leq d_1(x,y) \leq \sqrt{k}\ d_2(x,y)$$

Comment: Draw a picture when $k=2$. Is it clear enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.**

To prove $$d_2(x,y) \leq d_1(x,y)$$ square both sides.

To prove $$d_1(x,y) \leq \sqrt{k} d_2(x,y)$$ use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality as $$d_1(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}|x^i-y^i|=\vert x^1 - y^1 \vert . 1 + \dots + \vert x^k - y^k \vert . 1$$

Comment: Could I ask you to maybe go into a little bit more detail in the Cauchy-Schwartz part in proving the second inequality ?

Comment: My definition of Cauchy-Shwartz inequality is as follows: $|<x,y>| \leq \| x \| \|y \|$

Comment: Your definition of Cauchy-Schwartz inequality is correct. You can use it based on the new version of my answer.

Comment: This is what I am deducting from your hint , correct me where I am wrong:

Comment: Nope, never mind, I now fully understand.